# Buddypress jq.cookie not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, buddypress

Having some issues with Buddypress, I have installed nearly every version since 2.7 and I still get the same issue with

Uncaught TypeError: jq.cookie is not a function

I found in the folder

```
plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/_inc
```

there is a js file called

```
global.js
```

first line in this file is

```js
var jq = jQuery;
```

I realise this is not correct as my jQuery uses $ not jQuery

I tried changing this, however.
console log still shows that its not a found function.

I'm using $. cookies in other javascript. So jQuery cookies are installed.

Also, no matter what i change in this global.js
it still results in the same output as a

```
@   VM31193:1784
```

in chrome inspector as the original file.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: $ is an alias for jQuery

Comment: thanks how ever i already stated that above.

found out the issue was caused by ajaxify causing issues